# I know this regex can be simplified - .NET

Tags: .net, regex

Here are my requirements:

- 1-80 characters
- These characters are allowed:

  - alphanumeric
  - spaces
  - `_  (  )  [  ]  !  #  ,  .  &  *  +  :  '  / -`

The regex I have below works, but in particular I'm not sure how to reuse the character class `[\w\(\)\.\-\[\]!#,&*+:'\/]`

```
[\w\(\)\.\-\[\]!#,&*+:'\/][\w\s\(\)\.\-\[\]!#,&*+:'\/]{0,79}
```

**Update:**

Thanks for all your answers, this one did the trick

```
^(?!\s)[\w\s().\-!#&]{1,80}$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first character can't be white space try this:
`(?!\s)[-\w\s().[\]\\!#,&*+:'/]{1,80}`. You may want to "bracket" with ^ in the beginning and $ at the end `^(?!\s)[-\w\s().[\]\\!#,&*+:'/]{1,80}$`, to have the regex match the whole string.

Comment: You can drop the brackets around `\s`. Other than that, I like this one best.

Comment: Oh, and you might want to anchor it with `^` and `$` - but that's for the OP to decide.

Comment: "test test test" fails because space is not in the class.  I made that mistake in my first version, like the \\ which is also still here but shouldn't be.

Answer (score 4):

Does it really need to be 100% regex? Couldn't you just do

```
[\w\s\(\)\.\-\[\]!#,&*+:'\/]{1,80}
```

and separately verify that the first character isn't whitespace?

Answer (score 3):

Inside a character class, only `]` and `\` need escapes.  Even `-` doesn't need an escape if it's the first character of the class!

Here's the simplest regex I could reduce it to:

```
[- \w().[\]!#,&*+:'/]{1,80}
```

Comment: Make sure you don't use the ignore white space flag with this.

Comment: Also this will only match spaces (\0x20) and not any other white space characters. This may be exactly what you want, but watch out for Unicode spaces and such like.

Comment: `-` also needs no escaping as the last character in the class: `[a-z-]`, or directly positioned after a range: `[a-c-d]` (matches `a-c`, `-` or `d`). And even `]` needs no escaping if it's the first character in the class: `[]a]` matches an `]` or `a`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a negative look ahead to check the first character is not white space. Then there is no need to reuse a character class.

```
(?!\s)[\w\s\(\)\.\-\[\]!#,&*+:'\/]{1,80}
```